# Ubuntu SSH communcation

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine, scp

I have installed to 2 Ubuntu on VMware and i m trying to communicate between 2 machines using `ssh`.

I made the following changes
Updated the etc/host files on 2 machines Master and Slave with ips

```
127.0.0.2   slave
127.0.0.3   master
```

and created a key to communicate between the two machines.

When I try to copy the file from master to slave its copying into the master and not to the slave:

```
sh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@slave
```

Trying to copy from master to slave

```
scp -r /usr/local/somedir user@slave:/home/user/Downloads/Somethings
```

Could you please let me know where exactly I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you've done here. Who's the slave and who's the master? Are they both running in virtual machines? What is the host OS? Can you actually access these machines using the IPs you added to `hosts`?

Assuming your question is only about copying ssh keys around, you need to copy your key to the machines you want to log in to. So, if you are logged in to the "slave", run

```
sh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@master
```

Now you can log on to master from slave without a password. You don't need to add anything to the `authorized_keys` file, that will be done automatically when you log in.

To log into slave from master, you will need to first log into master and then repeat the process:

```
sh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@slave
```

Comment: You're welcome. As others have pointed out your main problem will be the IPs you are using. That's why I asked if you can actually access the machines using them.

Answer (score 1):

> IPv4 network standards reserve the entire 127.0.0.0/8 address block for loopback purposes. That means any packet sent to one of those 16,777,214 addresses (127.0.0.1 through 127.255.255.255) will be looped back.

From

[Wikipedia: Localhost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)

This means that trying to access any IP in the 127.*.*.* range will access the **local** computer.

You need to set the IPs of the VMs to a private subnet allocated by VMware; to do that, set up an "Internal" type network adapter. The IPs should be automatically allocated by DHCP. See the VMware docs on the network editor applet.

Answer (score 0):

Your using loopback addresses, It looks up slave and that's pointing back to itself

You need to assign your machines local addresses ie. 192.168.0.x

Plus I cannot understand why you need to put the public key in the same hosts authorized_keys file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I put the public key to communicate between 2 machines without prompting for password everytime. I will try to change host file and try again.

Comment: The host file is the least of your worrys thats only to link names to ips, get it working with IP's first, you need to setup each host with a local IP address. I can't vouch for vmware but in qemu-kvm you have to setup a network first and then configure your hosts accordingly.